# Python files not running inside VSCode terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever I try to run python files inside VSCode, the terminal pops up but nothing happens as shown in the image. Even `Start REPL` gives the same output. The terminal is unresponsive always and nothing appears. The interpreter is selected as is evident from the pic. Any fix?

[image: The terminal that appears is empty]

Comment: Have you checked if the file path is correct?

Comment: I think you have opened output window. To open terminal hit Ctrl + `

Comment: file path is correct @Danielmagox,

Comment: That is the terminal window, see the terminal is highlighted. Ctrl+` opens the same thing

Comment: Try this: in the screenshot you shared, in top right, there is Python, click on that dropdown menu and select powershell

Answer (score 0):

A blank screen could mean that the terminal was never created properly and the terminal is fine, or maybe that the renderer is broken. so there're two ways you can try and see if the problem goes away:

> 1.Reset your default terminal with the following steps:

1. press **Ctrl+Shift+`** to open a new terminal;
2. click the drop-down menu and choose Select Default Shell:
   [image]
3. select Command Prompt ：
   [image]
   Reload window to make the setting work.

> 2.If the problem is caused because the renderer is broken,

1. Zoom in and out (Ctrl+=, Ctrl+-) will force the renderer to redraw everything
2. The terminal features both a canvas-based renderer (fast can have various problems) dom-based renderer (slower but less problems). Changing the renderer type can identify issues with a particular renderer, configure with these settings:

   ```
     "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom"      
     "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "canvas"
   ```

More information about terminal troubleshooting you can refer  to [Terminal issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Terminal-Issues#enabling-escape-sequence-logging).